# Power LED with flash

Tags: power-supply, led

I did a LED ring for video filming and it works fine with a 5 V powerbank source, but I would like to know if is possible to power the LEDs with a flash power source?

Comment: what is a "flash power source" ?

Comment: Do you mean the flash connector on the top of the camera? Edit: I'm not seeing any power pins so I think the answer is "no". https://www.dslrbodies.com/cameras/general-nikon-camera-info/nikon-hot-shoe-pin-outs.html

Comment: the power source would be the connectors to the light inside the original flash

Comment: @VOV -- Can you measure the power source?  We need to know its voltage, and how much power it can deliver.  A make and model of "flash power source" might do.  If you can take a few screws off (careful of high voltage -- watch the capacitor(s)!), you might be able to tell us (two lithium 26150's in series, or four 26150's in parallel, and measure the voltage of the cells.  If you can do that, we might be able to help you better. I'm going to guess that you should be able to use it.

Comment: Hi, thanks all for the help but I think I will use the ring as a video light and keep the flash as it is. but thank you all for the help

Answer (score 2):

Camera "Hot Shoes" do not provide power to the flash.

Comment: Not directly from the shoe, I have a godox 350 s flash and I was thinking about opening it and connect the power cables that go to the bolb light to the LED ring instead.

Comment: @vov unless the bulb is 5v then that wouldnt work without modification. And you have to know if it's a xenon bulb or other type with a trigger pin it's also not easy to do. Youd be easier off creating a new circuit from scratch. Google hot shoe trigger circuit npn for an idea on howto start

Comment: Hi, thanks all for the help ... but I think I can use the ring better as a continuous light actually.